# Substring of NSString is not found

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'd like to check if this string contains "gif" value inside. I'm trying to achive this goal doing this:

```
NSString *originalSourceLinkToContent = @"site_media/obrazki/2014/07/faa4f4da470d7650cffe88f70cde230b_cropped.gif?1404832"
NSRange isRange = [originalSourceLinkToContent rangeOfString:@"cropped"; options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if(isRange.location != 0) {
        //found it...
        NSLog(@"HAS STRING");

    } else {
        NSLog(@"HAS NO STRING");
            }
```

where originalSourceLinkToContent is my string. I always get "HAS NO STRING" message even if there is this substring. How to make it working? In android it is simple because there is a method for that and always woks. What is equivalent method in iOS?

Comment: In iOS it's called `rangeOfString:`, and it always works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NSNotFound` instead of `0`

```
NSString *str2 = @"site_media/obrazki/2014/07/faa4f4da470d7650cffe88f70cde230b_cropped.gif?1404832";
NSRange isRange = [str2 rangeOfString:@"cropped" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

//use `NSNotFound`

if(isRange.location != NSNotFound) {
    //found it...
    NSLog(@"HAS STRING");

} else {
    NSLog(@"HAS NO STRING");
}
```

This code will work

Comment: Thanks. I know where the mistake was but thank you for this comment